# Changing karma-jasmine version manually

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

Is it possible / Is it effective if we change the version of KARMA-JASMINE in package.json manually?

```
  "devDependencies": {
"angular-mocks": "^1.5.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8"
  }
}
```

for example I want to change the version of karma-jasmine stated above(which is ^0.3.8) in 2.0.0 without npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package.json tells npm which packages and versions to install whenever you run `npm install` or `npm update`. In changing the version manually in package.json you will tell npm to install that version (or higher) but it won't actually be installed until you run the npm install/update.

If you want to install a different package or version from what's declared in your package.json you can use `npm install yourPackage@1.33.7` for example.